# Why is my boot partition full?

Tags: debian, boot, hard-disk, initrd

When I run run `apt-get dist-upgrade`, I get

```
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64
zstd: error 25 : Write error : No space left on device (cannot write compressed block) 
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -9 -T0 25
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

That file that it says it failed to generate, is here, `/boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64`, you can see it's 70M.

```
$ exa -l /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64
.rw-r--r-- 73M root 22 Dec 10:51 /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64
```

It says it failed to generate this file, but the file is there. Moreover, if I jump onto boot I can see that there is still space for 69 MB,

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=zero bs=1MB
dd: error writing 'zero': No space left on device
70+0 records in
69+0 records out
69255168 bytes (69 MB, 66 MiB) copied, 0.0888701 s, 779 MB/s
```

Why am I getting an error that there is no space on disk, and that `/boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64` failed to generate when,

- it's there
- there is 69 MB remaining on disk.

---

I can reproduce this error with this

```
update-initramfs -u -k 6.0.0-6-amd64
```

which is actually calling this under the hood to generate the error,

```
mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64.new 6.0.0-6-amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .rw-r--r-- 73M root 22 Dec 10:51 /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64
>
> [...]
>
> It says it failed to generate this file, but the file is there. Moreover, if I jump onto boot I can see that there is still space for 69 MB
> which is actually calling this under the hood to generate the error,
>
> mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-6-amd64.new 6.0.0-6-amd64

`mkinitramfs` tries to write to the temporary file with a `.new` extension, which doesn't exist. If it needs 73MB and you only have 69MB then it makes sense to fail.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Why would it generate the file in `/boot/` with `.new` instead of under `/tmp`? That's a really bad design decision.

Comment: It's a common practice to do it in the same directory. The reason is that `/boot` may be on a different partition than `/tmp` and that wouldn't allow an `mv` to succeed atomically (`mv` using hardlinks underneath). The goal is to reduce the amount of time that your system is left without a bootable configuration. And because generating or copying the file takes time and can fail, it instead does all the hard work on the `.new`, then deletes the old file and renames the new one, both of which are fairly instant processes. It may also rename the old one first instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was going on here, but I removed all things with that version number in boot

```
rm /boot/*6.0.0-6*
```

Then I reran `dist-upgrade`, which only generated the initramfs for the kernel I was running 6.0.0-4,

```
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-4-amd64
mkinitramfs -o /boot/initrd.img-6.0.0-4-amd64.new 6.0.0-4-amd64
```

Interesting, using `dpkg -l` I could see that even though I used rm to delete all things `6.0.0-6` the system *thought* the package `linux-image-6.0.0-6-amd64` was installed successfully: that package must install the kernel and view that as success regardless of whether or not the initramfs generation works.

What I did was run

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-6.0.0-6-amd64
```

To give the whole thing another go, and it worked..

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l /boot`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov updated

Comment: Evan, the wise approach is to remove old kernels and unnecessary files and then update.

Comment: @RomeoNinov there was one kernel in there, the one I was running. I was trying to dist-upgrade. Which installs a second kernel.

Comment: If purged in advance you will have no such error (about disk space).

Comment: In such case you size `/boot` too small.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, obviously that would fix it, but your comment here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729362/3285 was incorrect. That was the root cause. In order to upgrade a kernel on Debian you must have the space for 3 kernels/initrds in `/boot` not 2.